# How is the remaining number in this case an odd number?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, parity

My question goes like this.

Write the numbers $1,\ 2,\ 3,\dots,\ 2n$ on a paper, where $n$ is an odd number.
Name this list as $l_{2n}$ where $2n$ represents the number of terms in the list. Now choose any two numbers $j$ and $k$ at random from this list. Calculate $\vert j - k\vert$, then remove the numbers $j$ and $k$ from the list and add the number $\vert j-k\vert$ in the list. So we get a new list $l_{2n-1}$ with $2n-1$ terms.

For example, if $n=7$, we write the numbers
$$1,\ 2,\ 3,\ 4,\ 5,\ 6,\ 7,\ 8,\ 9,\ 10,\ 11,\ 12,\ 13,\ 14$$
Now, we choose two numbers at random, say $6$ and $11$. Now, $\vert6-11\vert=5$. So we remove $6$ and $11$ from the list and add $5$ in it (despite the fact that there is already a $5$). So the new list (with one less number of terms than the previous list) is
$$1,\ 2,\ 3,\ 4,\ 5,\ 7,\ 8,\ 9,\ 10,\ 12,\ 13,\ 14,\ 5$$

Now the problem is to prove that given an odd number $n$ and the starting list $1,\ 2,\ 3,\dots,\ 2n$, if we go on doing the above procedure iteratively on each new list, we always reach an odd number i.e. $l_1$ contains just one term which is always an odd number.

Now by studying proof theory, I have concluded that this theorem can be proved by contradiction. I can suppose that the value of $l_1$ is an even number and then backtrack to reach a contradiction to the hypothesis. But I don't know how to do it. Should I keep track of the parities of each number removed or added to the list (which is a difficult thing) or should I just stick to the parity of the end result (which I know is odd but can't prove it). Please help me to do the proof.

Comment: Here is a hint for a different approach: note that you are only interested in the parity of the final answer.

Comment: Think about the $3$ possible combinations of odds and evens that you can choose for $j$ and $k$.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Sorry but I can't get your point. Which 3 combinations are you talking about?

Comment: $j$ and $k$ are both odd, one is odd and one is even, both are even. Now consider the effect each case will have on the list.

Comment: By considering cases like @DonaldSplutterwit suggested, can you say something about the "number of odd numbers" in your list? Is there something special about the number of odds remaining?

Comment: I still don't get the point. What do you mean??

Comment: At the start there are $n$ odd numbers on the list (and $n$ even numbers too). If your first step is combining two even numbers, how many odd numbers will there be on the list? If you instead combine an odd and an even number, how many odd numbers are there on the list? If you combine two odd numbers, what happens then? So as the list gets smaller, what can you say about the number of odd numbers on the list?